# Abstract Class Initialization in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, abstract-class

I'm currently studying for the AP Computer Science exam. I see some questions which could have a abstract class such as

```
public abstract class ConstructionWorker {
     public ConstructionWorker() {
         // implimentation
     }

     // other methods
}
```

And another class such as

```
public class Carpenter extends COnstructionWorker {
     public Carpenter() {
         super()
     }
}
```

What would the differences in initializing the object be between these two things?

```
ConstructionWorker bob = new Carpenter();
Carpenter jane = new Carpenter();
```

Answer (score 3):

That's an example of [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). In both cases, you're constructing a `Carpenter` instance, but in the first case, you're storing it as a `ConstructionWorker`, which means you can only access `ConstructionWorker` members through it (unless you cast it back to `Carpenter`).

Under the hood, they're still both `Carpenter` instances - you're just accessing one of them as a `ConstructionWorker` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, every `Carpenter` is an instance of `ConstructionWorker` but now the other way around, which means when you assign a Carpenter to an ConstructionWorker you can only use methods declared in the `ConstructionWorker` class. In other words you lose all methods that have been declared/overriden in the Carpenter class.